# Is there a function to count with condition in power bi?

Tags: powerbi

for example

```
CARD NO         NAME
101             David
101             David
101             David
101             David
102             James
102             James
```

The goal is to count if there are 4 rows that have the same number, in this case "101", count as 1.
If rows are more and less than 4 rows, will count as 0 every time like the following:

```
CARD NO         NAME       count
101             David        1
101             David
101             David
101             David
102             James        0
102             James
103             Dave         0
103             Dave
103             Dave
```

And there are million rows that look something like that.
How to write the function to accomplish this in Power BI?

Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a measure with code something like below, where you need to replace "Fact" with the actual name of your table.

```
Count = IF( COUNTROWS( Fact ) >= 4, 1, 0 )
```

Then you can obtain a result in the report using this measure.

[image: Result]

I don't think it is possible to have a value in the first row of each group and blank in the other rows, just as in your description. The reason is that Power BI always groups results based on unique set of values visible in the report. In this case, there are 3 unique sets: (101, David), (102, James), and (103, Dave). There are no way for Power BI to handle 4 rows in the table which have the same values (101, David) differently.

Let's be technically more accurate. It is the report visualization that queries the value of measure [Count] for (101, David). Actually, it requests result for every possible combination of Card Number and Name, emitting a query similar to this.

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    'Fact'[Card Number],
    'Fact'[Name],
    "Count", [Count]
)
```

With this query, DAX engine evaluates [Count] in the filter context of every combination of Card Number and Name, for example Card Number = 101 and Name = David, and returns the result 1.

At this point, there is no way for DAX to discriminate each individual rows in the underlying table which have the same value combination, such as (101, David). In other words, it cannot find (101, David) of the specific row at first position in the table, but not the second, third, or forth positions, because there is no key to discriminate these 4 rows. They are all the same for DAX.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll try it